# Out of nowhere the mouseover and mouseleave doesn't work on mobile browser

Tags: javascript

Before i can click the icon in order to see it in mobile browser now it is not working anymore. it just console warning with this word "Element.setCapture() is deprecated. Use Element.setPointerCapture() instead. For more help [https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture"](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture%22)
This is my javascript code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{
const target = document.querySelectorAll(".hov");
const tooltips = document.querySelectorAll(".tltip");

target.forEach((tg, index)=> {
    tg.addEventListener("pointerover",() =>{
        let kswe = tg.previousElementSibling;
        kswe.style.display = 'block';
    });

    tg.addEventListener("pointerout",() =>{
        let kswe = tg.previousElementSibling;
        kswe.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
});
```

In web browser it is still working but not in mobile browser especially in firefox.

Im thinking of using a setPointerCapture() but i don't know where to start since it's an Instance Method not an Event. Also im using vanilla Js and not planning to use any frameworks or library.